# How to write on-* event/callback registration in dart

Tags: javascript, events, dart

I have a JavaScript class that has some events and I need to rewrite it to Dart. I dont know how to rewrite part where we use callbacks. This is my example code:

```
var Person = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.onNameChangedCallbacks = [];
}

Person.prototype.onNameChanged = function(callback) {
  this.onNameChangedCallbacks.push(callback);
}

Person.prototype.setName = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.onNameChangedCallbacks.forEach(function (callback){
    callback(name);
  });
}

var adam = new Person('Adam');

adam.onNameChanged(function(newName) {
  alert('New name is set to: ' + newName);
});

adam.setName('eva');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R79Vy/

As you can see whe anytime when name is changed all registered callbacks are called with new name parameter. How do you write this code in dart? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a custom event

```dart
elem.on['name-changed'].listen((e) {
  // handle event
});
```

if it is a DOM event there are usually specific getters like

```dart
elem.onNameChanged.listen((e) {
  // handle event
});

// or

elem.onNameChanged.listen((e) =>  /* handle event (inline function body) */);
```

You can also pass a method

```dart
elem.onNameChanged.listen(nameChangeHandler);

void nameChangeHandler(e) {
  // handle event
}
```

When you want to unsubscribe explicitely (not depend on garbage collection)

```dart
import 'dart:async';
StreamSubscription nameChangeSubscr;

nameChangeSubscr = elem.onnameChanged.listen((e) => /* handle event */);

// unsubscribe
if(nameChangeSubscr != null) nameChangeSubscr.cancel();
```

If you want a getter for custom events like DOM events have
[How do I fire a custom event from Polymer Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971511)

#### update

maybe this is what you want

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class Person {
  Stream onNameChange;
  //StreamController _controller = new StreamController();
  StreamController _controller = new StreamController.broadcast();
  Person() {
    onNameChange = _controller.stream;
  }

  String _name;
  String get name => _name;
  set name(String val) {
    _name = val;
    _controller.add(val);
  }
}

void main() {
  var p = new Person();
  StreamSubscriptions nameChangeSubscr = p.onNameChange.listen((e) => print('name changed: $e'));


  var i = 0;
  new Timer.periodic(new Duration(milliseconds: 300), (Timer t) {
    if(i > 5) {
      t.cancel();
      if(nameChangeSubscr != 0) nameChangeSubscr.cancel();
    }
    p.name = "name ${i++}";
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where is my Person class? What's elem? My Person class doesn’t have any on, onNameChanged methods yet. I don't know how to implement them.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very fluent in JavaScript and saved the time to investigate thoroughly. I'll extend my answer

Comment: Do you really want to register callback this way or do you just need a method to get notified about changes like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276737

Comment: This works, but not as expected. Scenario: Change name, then subscribe, then again change name => should call callback once, but it actually calls it twice.

Comment: You are right, the previous version buffers events and sends them when a listener subscribes. The current version doesn't do this anymore.